# Android service has to be static and can't reference my text input which implements findViewById

Tags: android, service, findviewbyid

Basically I have created an app into which the user enters a number (in seconds). They then click a button and a service is created which runs a countdown starting at the number of seconds entered. However in my service I reference variables such as:

```
public EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
int Time = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
```

This 'breaks' the service as it is static and can't reference findViewById.
I have tried for hours to work around this but I have no clue, any help much appreciated!

Comment: Is the TextView used to display the countdown timer? If so, you don't need a `service`. Use `AsyncTask` instead.

Comment: I am sure that services are used for background work something that has no intervention from the user which make it inappropriate if it has EditText or any other view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does the `Service` have to be `static`? A `Service` should be either started/stopped or bound/unbound (or a combination of the two). You shouldn't have to create a `static` Android `Service`.

Put this code into your `Activity` and not the `Service`...

```
public EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
int time = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
```

...then just pass the time to the `Service` in the `Intent` you use to start it...

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
i.putExtra("the_time", time);
startService(i);
```

Then in the `Service` `onStartCommand(...)` method use...

```
int time = intent.getIntExtra("the_time", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Squonk. To answer your question, I have to create a static Android service because otherwise when I view the service in the application tab of the manifest (using Eclipse) it says this 'dummyservice is enclosed, but not static' and it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1861636 : I don't understand why eclipse would say something like that - you must have something strange in your code. Either way, you can't use `findViewById(...)` in a `Service` simply because a `Service` isn't a UI framework and doesn't have a `View`. Even if you have a running `Activity` and a `Service`, the `Service` shouldn't be attempting to access any part of the `Activity` directly. Simply pass the data from the `Activity` to the `Service` using the code I show in my answer.

Comment: One last thing, if I want to update a textbox showing the amount of time left can I pass the countdown value to the main activity from the service when the application is in the foreground?

Comment: Tried to do what you said and got this 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getIntExtra(String, int) from the type Intent' Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to make things `static` in your `Service`. As for updating a `TextView` in your `Activity` you will need to use something like an inner `BroadcastReceiver` or perhaps a `ResultReceiver` passed in the `Intent`.

Comment: I'm not trying to make anything static, I don't mention static anywhere in my code, I'll just try work around by using AsyncTask instead

Comment: Firstly you should be using `@Override` for the `onStartCommand(...)` method and secondly it has the following form... `public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {...}`. Finally, you should be using `intent` (lower-case 'i') when calling `getIntExtra(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but it doesn't seem to be working, I'll plough on with something else. Cheers